# Im creating a discord bot , and when i try to run it(using the command node . )

Tags: javascript

It keeps giving me an error that the module cant be found . I reinstalled node but it still gave me the same error , then i reinstalled discord.js but it was the same.
CODE:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

const token = '(actual token here)';

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'ping') {
    msg.reply('Pong!');
  }
});

client.login('token');
```

ERROR:

```
PS C:\Users\Admin> node .
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
 throw err;
 ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Admin'
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
   at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
   at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
 code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
 requireStack: []
}
```

Comment: can you include code and error to the question rather than external link?

Comment: i added them , sorry for forgetting about them but i thought the pics would work since this is the first time im posting here . Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you make sure node and djs are in the same folder as the file?